# Effect of mail bombing

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, memory

I have option in my application which send an invitation email to another user. 
Someday ago, one of my friend told me that, attacker can flood any email using this function. And i have checked that this is true.

But, is this really something bad for my application ? I mean memory corruption or any other matter ?

What you think researchers ?

Regards

**Addition:**
I am using a random token in that function. Which will invalid after logout. But with burp suit it is possible to repeat.

Comment: This is considered a replay attack. Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack for counter measurements.

Comment: edited my thread

Comment: Another option could be to implement request based tokens rather than session based tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the greatest threat could be Denial of service, you could send so many e-mails you could saturate your SMTP server, your mail server and your user´s personal inbox.

Comment: How could this saturate my SMTP and mail server ?

Comment: Everytime you use your SMTP server to send an e-mail it enters a queue and they are processed in the order they are received, send enough spam at the same time and your queue waiting time will increase preventing legitimate e-mails to be sent on time. Send even more and the SMTP server memory will saturate and crash the server. On the mail server if it is storing the e-mails, eventually it could fill the HDD.

Comment: this is make sense. But what if my server is strong enough ?

Comment: I believe there is no "strong enough" server that wont fall eventually to a denial of service attack, but you should also consider what Lawtonfogle is saying in the next answer.

Comment: Look, user should repeat the request. I mean for denial of service attack, you should send large packet's again and again. With little packet, you can't do dos attack in a system.  
Lawtonfogle answer might not related to my question.

Comment: You are wrong, DoS does not necessarily need large packets, a large number of small packets will suffice, in fact, DoS attacks like the famous Ping of death consist in sending thousands of pings (which are small packets) to the same server at the same time.

Comment: Here is the problem Kotzu. SMTP will not act like any other transfer protocol. In case of mass emails SMTP will send these mass emails to queue folder. And will be sent one by one. So, all request will wait into queue folder but actually they are freeze there. But with big packet, possibly it may point of dos attack.

Comment: Yes and that queue folder is in the RAM which can be saturated as well as your network connection. I agree this is a low risk scenario if you are confident your infrastructure can tolerate it, but it is a risk anyways.

Comment: Your explanation is nice. It makes sense the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If a user can get your email server to spam emails, it could increase the likelihood that all emails from you are automatically marked as spam.  In the worst case, you could end up on [email blacklists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) and emails you send could be completely ignored.

This is assuming you are running all parts of this on your own servers.  If not, you might want to clarify.

Comment: user can't do anything just send the invitation request.

Comment: Which causes your email server to send out an email, right?

Comment: yes.But why it will be spam ?

Comment: 1 email isn't a problem.  1,000,000 emails is.  The exact algorithms that companies use to blacklist/mark as spam aren't known, but massive redundant emails to many targets and numerous emails to the same target is very likely to set them off.  Basically ask yourself, "does it look like spam?"  In this case, what the attacker is doing will look like spam, but from you.  So you are blacklisted.

Comment: I understood your answer. But it's not that matter i have asked. I am asking about my application system problem.And it's vulnerability.

Comment: I'm pointing out how this can impact the application's security by damaging part of the app's CIA Triad.  Your Availability will be damaged and others will react as if your integrity is damaged (via the blacklisting).  In simplest form, I am saying "Yes, this is something bad for your application."

Answer (score 0):

If you have an email destination that spawns another email destination, there's a chance that will turn into a feedback loop. At it's most efficient, the smtp might deliver your mail to your local destination before it receives a resend, i.e. you lose disk space. If it doesn't, you lose cpu cycles, and diskspace.

Comment: simply, after invitation sent, my smtp just send a mail to user's invited email id. So, where is loop ?